# how to run more instance jobs in parallel using Api REST runDSJob?

Tags: rest, multiple-instances, datastage

Using https://xx.xx.xx.x:9443/ibm/iis/api/dscdesignerapi?api=runDSJob&jobName=JobName.**instance**&projectName=ProjectName&hostName=Host.Name&getFullOutput=true&apiVersion=3.0

{
"JobStatus": "FWF",
"dataflowName": "JobName.**instance**",
"restApiName": "restRunDSJob",
"failureMessage": [
{
"errorStackTrace": "",
"errorException": "JobGetInfoException",
"errorMessage": "Failed to get "any field" from the job "JobName.**instance**" information."
}
],
"succeeded": false
}

.Using https://xx.xx.xx.x:9443/ibm/iis/api/dscdesignerapi?api=runDSJob&jobName=JobName&projectName=ProjectName&hostName=Host.Name&getFullOutput=true&apiVersion=3.0

Works

{
"result": "oshResult",
"JobStatus": "RUN",
"dataflowName": "JobName",
"restApiName": "restRunDSJob",
"succeeded": true
}

Answer (score 1):

You can call REST API to run multi-instance job using jobRunOptions to pass invocation id like below.

https://xx.xx.xx.x:9443/ibm/iis/api/dscdesignerapi?api=runDSJob&jobName=JobName&projectName=ProjectName&hostName=Host.Name&getFullOutput=true&apiVersion=3.0 -d '{"jobRunOptions": {"JOBINVOCATIONID": "A2A","Warning": "5"}}'